# Showing that $||V(f,x)||_{L^2((1,\infty),m)}\le C||f||_{L^p((1,\infty),m)}$

Tags: real-analysis, integration

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How can I give a bound on the $L^2$ norm of this function?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/245460/how-can-i-give-a-bound-on-the-l2-norm-of-this-function)

For $f\in L^p((1,\infty),m)$,  $2<p<4$,

Want to prove that there exists $C$ which only depends on $p$, such that

$$V(f,x)=\frac{1}{x}\int^{10x}_x\frac{f(t)}{t^{\frac{1}{4}}}dm(t)$$

satisfies

$$||V(f,x)||_{L^2((1,\infty),m)}\le C||f||_{L^p((1,\infty),m)}$$

Comment: I have seen a similar question on this website if it is not exactly the same.

Answer (score 0):

**Hint** Use [Holder's inequality](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/H%C3%B6lder%27s_inequality)

$$ \|fg\|_1 \le \|f\|_p \|g\|_q \quad \frac{1}{p}+\frac{1}{q} = 1, $$

and note that $ q=\frac{p}{p-1}. $